# Best practice to do multiple replicates with pouchdb?

Tags: javascript, synchronization, pouchdb

Since my app requires the complete event, I've moved my code from .sync to .replicate and I was wondering what is the best practice in term of synching over  some period of time.

At first, I replicate to and from, and I can store last_seq. For future replicate, should I pass it as the since parameter? Will it make synching faster and more efficient or does PouchDB already have this mechanism internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PouchDB already does that internally. The `update_seq` is saved as a checkpoint in both databases using a [`_local` document](http://pouchdb.com/guides/local-documents.html). (Unless your remote database is write-only, in which case PouchDB cannot write a checkpoint and therefore will replicate a bit more slowly.)